# Simple idea behind a database for a single website

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a website. I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.3. I have MySQL installed.
How hard can it be to send and receive data from this database, from the website? I don't know **[php](/questions/tagged/php)** yet, but I can learn it if that's necessary.
What I want is simply to, for example, have a form on a website which sends it's information to the database. I understand about the columns in the database, and I've created a database table thing on the MySQL workbench, but I don't know how to host this database, or how to access it from my website.
Even just some good links would be helpful, as I haven't found any.

Comment: There are plenty of PHP and MySQL tutorials out on the web and in books. Go forth and have fun.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
___Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you or do your Google searches for you___

Comment: Google is your friend : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: On a hardness scale from 1 being soft to 10 being hard, I'd rate this type of thingy idea at about 2.

Comment: Do you have a web site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually can Google but you can go try to learn at the links below:

1. [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com/php/default.asp)
2. [php.net](http://php.net)

And you need to learn **[sql](/questions/tagged/sql)** too. For **[sql](/questions/tagged/sql)**, this links can help you:

1. [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)
2. [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/)

Hope this links will make your job easier.
And a quick tutorial by me:

> `mysql_*` commands are no longer available. Use **mysqli** or **PDO**.

**Connecting To Your Database:**

---

*Using `mysqli`*

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

?>
```

---

*Using `PDO:`*

```
<?php

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);

?>
```

Hope everything will work fine, happy coding!

Comment: thank you! the section about Using mysqli is what I really wanted, i'm sure it'll help a lot :)

Comment: @JacobGarby Happy Coding ;)